# Why is this string comparison not working? C

Tags: c, string, comparison

I'm trying to compare if user input is the same as in text file. in `printf("U = %s, R = %s.", uAts, rline);`line i get that a = a, but it still goes to else statement. Maybe there is like some other method for comparing strings in C  language which I don't know?

```
void nextQ(int klL, FILE *kl, FILE *ats, FILE *atsR){
    int i, uAts[500], at;
    char kline[500], aline[500], rline[500], b[1];
    system("cls");

    for (i = 0; i <= klL; i++){
        fgets(kline, 500, kl);
        fgets(aline, 500, ats);
        fgets(rline, 500, atsR);
 }
    printf("%s\n", kline);
    printf("%s\n\n", aline);
    printf(rline);

    printf("Jusu atsakymas: ");
    scanf("%s", &uAts);
    printf("U = %s, R = %s.", uAts, rline);
        if(uAts == rline){
            printf("Klausimas atsakytas teisingai!\n");
            printf("Noredami pereiti prie kito klausimo iveskite bet koki simboli ");
            scanf("%s", b);     
            nextQ(klL+1, kl, ats, atsR);        
        }else{
            printf("Neteisingai\n");
        }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pas, klL = 0;
    char term;
    bool menu = true;

    //textiniu failu nuskaitimas
    FILE *kl;
    kl = fopen("Klausimai.txt", "r");
    FILE *ats;
    ats = fopen("Atsakymai.txt", "r");
    FILE *laim;
    laim = fopen("Laimejimas.txt", "r");
    FILE *atsR;
    atsR = fopen("AtsR.txt", "r");

    do{
        //menu
        printf("1. Pradeti zaidima.\n");
        printf("2. Iseiti\n");
        printf("Jusu pasirinkimas: ");
        scanf("%d%c", &pas, &term);

        if(pas < 1 || pas > 2 || term != '\n'){
            printf("\nBloga ivestis");
            break;
        }else{
        nextQ(klL, kl, ats, atsR);
        }
    }while(menu);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &uAts);` will invoke *undefined behavior* by passing pointer to object having wrong type to `scanf`: `%s` calls for `char*`, but you passed `char(*)[500]`

Comment: using `scanf("%s", b);` with `char b[1];` is also bad because considering the terminating null-character, it can only read zero character without causing out-of-range access, which invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `printf(rline);` is another bad thing because it will invoke *undefined behavior* for luck of data if user input something like `%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s`

Comment: Also don't forget to remove the newline character read via `fgets()` to do proper comparision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the issues mentioned in the comments: you can't compare strings like that:

```
if(uAts == rline)
```

That wil compare the **addresses** of the char arrays and these will always be different. Use

```
if( strcmp( uAts, rline ) == 0 )
```

instead. `strcmp()` will compare the **contents** of two NUL terminated char arrays (aka "strings" in C).

Comment: Nice answer. I especially like that you clarify there is no true string type in C. Too bad this is a dup (or a dup of a dup, ... - dups all the way down:-).